# git push commit to different branch

Tags: git, push, bitbucket, commit

Sorry, this maybe a stupid question, but I just couldn't figure it out the problem.

I have cloned a branch via **git (bitbucket)**, changed some files, commited these and pushed them back to the remote origin.

Now I want to push this commit to a different branch which is partly ahead and behind of the current branch. So I tried: `git push origin HEAD:differentBranch`, but this didn't work ("Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote counterpart").

How can I fix this? Sorry again, my skills in git are still developable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by using [git cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).
So you can try like this:

```
git checkout differentBranch
git cherry-pick <commit # from previous commit from your first branch>
```